# Read Outlook Events via Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, outlook-2010, win32com

Outlook has some things to desire - like showing multiple month view

I decided to give it a try by pulling out the event data via Python (and then figure a way to display it nicely). Google is giving poor results.

My goals are:

- read a shared calendar
- read the events information like start, end, subject, creator, etc.

This is what I got together (with inspiration from [this site](http://cephas.net/blog/2004/09/17/sending-your-outlook-calendar-using-python/))

```
import win32com.client, datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

appointments = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items 
# TODO: Need to figure out howto get the shared calendar instead Default [9] 
# (I have placed the shared folder into a separate folder - don't know if it matters)
# I would just like the user to select which calendar to execute on
appointments.Sort("[Start]")
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"
begin = date.today().strftime("%m%d%Y")
end = (date.today() + relativedelta( months = 3 )).strftime("%m%d%Y")
appointments = appointments.Restrict("[Start] >= '" +begin+ "' AND [END] >= '" +end+ "'")
```

How do I loop through the events and read them?

Comment: Did you mean `ns.GetDefaultFolder(9)` instead of `namespace.`? I get a NameError if I try your code.

Answer (score 26):

> From here I need help with looping through the events and read them.

Basically, all you have to do is to follow the COM API documentation from Microsoft. For example, the `Restrict()` method returns `AppointmentItem` objects which are documented at [AppointmentItem Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869026%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for Outlook 2010. So, starting with a folder, you can get and list the appointments as follows:

```
# Get the AppointmentItem objects
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210899(v=office.11).aspx
appointments = someFolder.Items

# Restrict to items in the next 30 days (using Python 3.3 - might be slightly different for 2.7)
begin = datetime.date.today()
end = begin + datetime.timedelta(days = 30);
restriction = "[Start] >= '" + begin.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "' AND [End] <= '" +end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "'"
restrictedItems = appointments.Restrict(restriction)

# Iterate through restricted AppointmentItems and print them
for appointmentItem in restrictedItems:
    print("{0} Start: {1}, End: {2}, Organizer: {3}".format(
          appointmentItem.Subject, appointmentItem.Start, 
          appointmentItem.End, appointmentItem.Organizer))
```

Note that I had to use a slightly different time format for the restriction expression (`"%m/%d/%Y"` instead of `"%m%d%Y"`). The proper solution would be to use Outlook's `Format` function as documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.14).aspx, section *Date*. Note also that I was using Python 3.3, so you might have to use different functions to create the dates. In any case, for testing purposes, you can use a hard coded expression like `"[Start] >= '02/03/2014' AND [End] <= '03/05/2014'"`

To get a shared calendar, the following code should work - This is the usual sequence found in the API documentation, however I was not able to actually get it working, but this could be due to a different backend server (not using an Exchange server):

```
recipient = namespace.createRecipient("User Name")
resolved = recipient.Resolve()
sharedCalendar = namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9)
```

To show all available folders as a tree, you can use something like

```
def folderTree(folders, indent = 0):
    prefix = ' ' * (indent*2)
    i = 0
    for folder in folders:
        print("{0}{1}. {2} ({3})".format(prefix, i, folder.Name, folder.DefaultItemType))
        folderTree(folder.Folders, indent + 1)
        i = i + 1

...
folderTree(namespace.Folders)
```

To look up a folder by its path (e.g. to find the calendar folder "Norfeld@so.com" below the "Internet Calendars" folder), you can use something like

```
def findFolder(folders, searchPath, level = 0):
    for folder in folders:
        if folder.Name == searchPath[level]:
            if level < len(searchPath)-1:
                # Search sub folder
                folder = findFolder(folder.folders, searchPath, level+1)
            return folder
    return None

...
sharedCalendar = findFolder(namespace.Folders, ["Internet Calendars", "Norfeld@so.com"])
```

See also:

- [Outlook Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870566%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Some more samples how to use the COM API](https://github.com/afester/CodeSamples/blob/master/Python/Sample/src/samplePackage/SampleModule.py) (as part of my "Python samples" project)
- [A standalone Python script to show the folders tree and to lookup folders by path name](https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/blob/master/Python/Win32Com/COMsample.py)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - so my restriction string command was wrong. I find it hard to understand the MS API. How would I go about selecting another calendar than the default. Thinking that a loop through the names of all calendars would be nice.

Comment: I agree that the COM API is not easy to read - but basically, the model is easy: There are objects which have Methods and Properties (and Events). Methods can be called and might return a result, like a reference to another object. Properties can be read (and written if not read-only), and reading might result again in references to another object. Some methods/properties return COM collections which can be iterated, which is seamlessly integrated into Python so that you can use `for ... in ...`.

Comment: It's not that I didn't try. But just can't make your folderTree work - which I need in order to grab the calendar of interest. I'm not using classes in python.

Comment: `for folder in ns.Folders: print folder.Name` gives me "Internet Calendars" "SharePoint Lists" "my@mail.com"

Comment: Lets say I want to grab a calendar in the "Internet Calendars" - how would I define a recipient name as a string that grabs a calendar in the "Internet Calendars" folder

Comment: Please see my updated answer - I have changed the code so that it does not use classes, and I also provided a link to a standalone script which lists the folder tree, looks up a specific folder by its path (such as "Internet Calendars" => "Name@mail.com") and lists items from this calendar. I suggest that you use this script as a starting point, and see if you can get it to run in your environment . If it does not run, I suggest that you post a followup question with the specific error code / issue where you are stuck, so that the context of this question is retained