# Automatic categorisation of emails at certain times

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a recurring calendar event in outlook, and I would like to apply a category to every email that I receive during that event.

(How) Is this possible?

Thanks
Ol1ve

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://pyexchange.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477599/read-outlook-events-via-python Also, you have put some effort from your side else no one might response to your question. Its too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The simplest scenario is to handle the *NewMailEx* event of the *Application* class. In the event handler you can check whether any event is active at the moment. If so, you can add a category to the incoming email message. Also you may consider handling the ItemAdd event of the Inbox folder in the store (to avoid known issues with the NewMail/NewMailEx event).

Finally, I'd recommend reading the [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/) series of articles that describe known pitfalls and provide possible workarounds.