# Matching Outlook Calendar Dates to CSV Dates and Appending Match to List

Tags: python, csv, outlook, calendar

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to Python. I am attempting to write a script that will go through a CSV, check if certain columns match Outlook calendar items (by subject, organizer, and date match), and then have the script note that there was a successful match in a new column (I stole heavily from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477599/read-outlook-events-via-python)). Below is my whole script.

```
import win32com.client, datetime, re, os, csv, shutil

# set cwd, create copy of original CSV, and access outlook API
os.chdir('C:\\')
shutil.copy('masterCheck.csv', 'inspectCheck.csv')
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inspectors = {'ASMITH': 'Smith, Aaron', 'JDOE': 'Doe, Jane', 'KZEEBOP': 'Zeebop, Kim'}

#access csv and put it into a list
with open('inspectCheck.csv', 'r', newline = '', encoding='utf-8') as csvAppointments:
    reader = csv.reader(csvAppointments)
    masterList = list(reader)
    del masterList[-1] # delete blank nested list
    del masterList[1] #delete header
    for i in masterList: # switch out names so they can match Outlook descriptors later
        for key, value in inspectors.items():
            if i[3] in key:
                i[3] = value

# create another list for appending later in the script
finalList = []
finalList += masterList

# access the inspectors' calendars
x = 0
try:
    for inspector in inspectors.values():
        recipient = outlook.createRecipient(inspector)
        resolved = recipient.Resolve()
        sharedCalendar = outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9)
        codeAppointments = sharedCalendar.Items

        #restrict to items in the next year
        begin = datetime.date.today()
        end = begin + datetime.timedelta(days = 365);
        restriction = "[Start] >= '" + begin.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "' AND [End] <= '" +end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "'"
        restrictedItems = codeAppointments.Restrict(restriction)

        # loop through inspectors' appointments and match
        for appointmentItem in restrictedItems:
            for i in masterList:
                addressSearch = i[1]
                if re.search(r'%s' % addressSearch, appointmentItem.Subject, re.IGNORECASE)\
                   and i[3] in appointmentItem.Organizer\
                   and i[4] in appointmentItem.Start:
                    finalList[x].append(appointmentItem.Subject)
                    x += 1
except IndexError:
    pass

# update spreadsheet
with open('inspectCheckFinal.csv', 'w', newline = '') as csvAppointments:
    appointmentsWriter = csv.writer(csvAppointments)
    appointmentsWriter.writerows(finalList)
```

I have had success matching columns from my CSV to Outlook items. For example, I can get this to match.

```
if re.search(r'%s' % addressSearch, appointmentItem.Subject, re.IGNORECASE)
```

However, as soon as I try to match it to my date column (i[4]), it throws the error: **TypeError: argument of type 'pywintypes.datetime' is not iterable**. The dates in my CSV look like *2/11/2018* but the dates (when printed) in Outlook look like *2017-11-16 11:00:00+00:00*. I'm at a loss on how to match these two.

Moreover, I am having trouble marking the CSV with successful matches. While the script will append a value to the end of each nested list (and then write it to a CSV), it will not append the value to the matched row of the CSV. For example, my output looks like:

```
Inspector     |Address     |Date     |Success?(print Address)
ASMITH        |212 Clark St|11/21/18 |Yes. 33 Blart Ave
ASMITH        |33 Blart Ave|11/20/18 |Yes. 212 Clark St
```

My guess is that my script finds a match in Outlook, and then appends that value to the end of a nested list. What I would like it to do is to match it in the row/nested list where it was actually matched. Apologies for the long post and thank you to those who read it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved the TypeError by converting

```
and i[4] in appointmentItem.Start:
# to
and i[4] in str(appointmentItem.Start):
```

Moreover, I reformatted my CSV beforehand so it will now match Outlook's format. As for my matches being appended in the wrong rows, I think I will solve that by appending matches to a separate CSV/dataframe, and then joining that dataframe to the original CSV/dataframe.