# Read Outlook Shared Calendars via Python

Tags: python, automation, outlook, win32com, outlook-2010

Using Python, how do you read Outlook's Shared Calendar events, and hopefully, also using a **time filter**?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477599/read-outlook-events-via-python) is a relevant post, but to answer this fully:

```py
import win32com.client  # for outlook
import datetime

"""This code reads shared calendars."""

# set variables
days = 3
begin = datetime.date.today()
end = begin + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
events = []  # to write results from calendar loop

# begin importing calendar
Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# turn this into a list to read more calendars
recipient = ns.CreateRecipient("username")  # cmd whoami to find this
resolved = recipient.Resolve()  # checks for username in address book

# olFolderCalendar = 9
# appointments = ns.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items  # for personal calendar
appointments = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9).Items

# filtering criteria
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences
appointments.Sort("[Start]")  # suspect problem
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"
restriction = "[Start] >= '" + begin.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") \
            + "' AND [End] <= '" + end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "'"

# list of appointments
restrictedItems = appointments.Restrict(restriction)

# loop through all calendar events, and add elements to list
count = 0
for app in restrictedItems:
    count += 1  # no len(range(restrictedItems)) allowed

#   display values
    print()
    print("item: " + str(count))
    print("start: \t\t" + str(app.Start))
    print("subject: \t" + app.Subject)
    print("end: \t\t" + str(app.End))
    print("recurring: \t" + str(app.IsRecurring))
    print("status: \t" + str(app.MeetingStatus))

    # collect values
    app_instance = [app.Subject,
                    app.Start,
                    app.End,
                    app.BusyStatus]
    events.append(app_instance)
```

Comment: Nice, but working for 'my calendars' only (where you have an email account) not for shared calendars

Comment: @Andrew, good clarifications. I remember that you need to be granted read access to other Outlook calendars for this to work.