# Python get shared (REST) Outlook calendar events

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, calendar, office365

I'm trying to fetch events from a shared calendar. I have tried the solutions provided in the following link:
[Read Outlook Events via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477599/read-outlook-events-via-python)

However, this only reads MAPI and I want to read from a REST calendar.

Here's the calendar properties
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the post you mentioned the default calendar is used:

```
appointments = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items
```

It seems you need to choose another calendar in Outlook. You can find the required folder by using navigation modules and folders in Outlook. The [NavigationFolder.Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationfolder.folder) returns a `Folder` object that represents the shared or linked folder associated with the navigation folder. For example, here is a sample VBA code which shows how to get to the required folder:

```
Sub PrintAllSharedCalendars()
    Dim olPane As NavigationPane
    Dim olMod As CalendarModule
    Dim olGrp As NavigationGroup
    Dim olNavFld As NavigationFolder
    Dim olCalFld As Folder
    
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set olCalFld = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set olPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    Set olMod = olPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
    Set olGrp = olMod.NavigationGroups.Item("Shared Calendars")
   
    For i = 1 To olGrp.NavigationFolders.Count
        Set olNavFld = olGrp.NavigationFolders.Item(i)
        Debug.Print(olNavFld.Folder.Name)
    Next

End Sub
```

The Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications. So, I hope you  can easily find the required sequence of property and method calls to get it it running in python.